# rails join on association and id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to achieve something that takes exactly 3 seconds on SQL, and I'm struggling with it for hours, I want to load all records and left join if it exists, if not, then don't give me the associated model.

the query I want to create is as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM apartments LEFT JOIN comments ON apartments.id = comments.apartment_id AND comments.user_id = ?"
```

and when I call apartment.comments, it'll give me just the record (can only be one) for the specific user, not all the records for every user.

I tried

```
Apartment.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.apartment_id = apartments.id AND comments.user_id = #{user_id}")
```

but it doesn't work, as when I call apartments.comments it fires another query which returns all possible comments.

```
Apartment.includes(:comments).where("comments.user_id = ?", user_id)
```

doesn't work aswell, because it returns only apartments who has a comment from the specific user.

help is needed!

Comment: A lot of errors in your code. What is `LEFT JOIN ON` without table_name? Why tables names are different here: `LEFT OUTER JOIN trip_items ON comments.`?

Comment: you're correct, fixed. I copy paste and changed the names to make it more understanble

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
#app/models/apartment.rb
Class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
   scope :user, ->(id) { where("comments.user_id = ?", id }
end 

@apartment = Apartment.find(params[:id])
@comments = @apartment.comments.user(user_id)
```